# LIBUSB_ERROR_NOT_FOUND in python when trying jdmtool

Tags: python

I am trying to use JDMtool in macOS Mojave (python 3.11):

https://github.com/dimaryaz/jdmtool

to write my GNS430 datacards from my Jeppesen subscription.
The app works as I can login and download my subscription navigation data file but when try to access the card reader I get the following error:

```
(jdmtool) ~ ➤ jdmtool detect
Found device: Bus 020 Device 004: ID 0e39:1250
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/icordoba/anaconda3/envs/jdmtool/bin/jdmtool", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
             ^^^^^^
  File "/Users/icordoba/anaconda3/envs/jdmtool/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jdmtool/main.py", line 442, in main
    func(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/icordoba/anaconda3/envs/jdmtool/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jdmtool/main.py", line 66, in wrapper
    with handle.claimInterface(0):
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/icordoba/anaconda3/envs/jdmtool/lib/python3.11/site-packages/usb1/__init__.py", line 1146, in claimInterface
    mayRaiseUSBError(
  File "/Users/icordoba/anaconda3/envs/jdmtool/lib/python3.11/site-packages/usb1/__init__.py", line 127, in mayRaiseUSBError
    __raiseUSBError(value)
  File "/Users/icordoba/anaconda3/envs/jdmtool/lib/python3.11/site-packages/usb1/__init__.py", line 119, in raiseUSBError
    raise __STATUS_TO_EXCEPTION_DICT.get(value, __USBError)(value)
usb1.USBErrorNotFound: LIBUSB_ERROR_NOT_FOUND [-5]
```

I am pretty new to Python so I don't know how to install the required USB access library for JDMTool to be able to read and write the data card reader. Any indications please?